# “Avoir du talent” vs “être un talent”

Tags: grammaire, vocabulaire

**“Avoir du talent” vs “être un talent”:**

How different are they? Do they have the same meaning? E.g.

> Ma fille a le plus de talent. Mon fils est un talent.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with jlliagre, with just one precision :
*être un talent* can be used when talking about someone, but it's not frequent at all, except for this expression : *jeune talent*, which would mean *being a promising young one*.
Example :

> Ce garçon fait partie des jeunes talents de la chanson française.

Comment: Yes, that's why I wrote *generally*. *Être un talent* might refer to someone too, but is rare with that acception.

Answer (score 1):

They haven't the same meaning.

You say *avoir du talent* when talking about someone but *être un talent* is generally used when talking about the talent itself:

> Ce jeune artiste a du talent.
>
> C'est un talent caché que vous avez là !

Answer (score 0):

Some examples will make it clear.

> Ma fille a le **plus/moins de** talent. My daughter has the most/least talent.
>
> J'ai découvert que **j'ai du talent** **pour** m'exprimer en public. I discovered that I am good at speaking to an audience.
>
> Quel **est ton talent** caché que tu ne connais pas? What is your hidden talent that you do not know?
>
> Ils peuvent **être** très **talentueux** et performants. They may be very accomplished and competetive.